# ScrollViewer PointerMoved event can not be trigger when drag content to exceed top or bottom?(windowsphone8.1)

Tags: uwp

I have a ListView . I want gets the internal control Scollviewer PointerMoved event , when drag the listview items exceed top or bottom. when listview items can scroll , it tragger ok , but if I continue drag the items  ,items have a compression effect.At this time , Scollviewer PointerMoved  event cannot be trigger.
    Because I don't have a winphone, so I am using the simulator tests,I don't know if this is the emulator problem.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducable sample to attract more answers

Comment: Is this question about Win 8.1 oder Win 10? You're unclear here.